# Can typescript not infer the type of unique symbol passed directly into a function?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a utility like `ts-action` but with `symbol` as action type instead of `string`.

Typescript infers the symbol correctly when symbol is first declared as const. When symbol is passed directly into the function, typescript fails to infer the type. Is there something I do not know?

```js
interface Action<T extends symbol> {
    type: T;
}

function action<T extends symbol>(type: T): () => Action<T> {
    return () => ({ type });
}

const SOME_ACTION_TYPE = Symbol('some action type');
const actionBuilder = action(SOME_ACTION_TYPE);
type actionBuilderType = typeof actionBuilder;
// expected: () => Action<typeof SOME_ACTION_TYPE>
// actual: () => Action<typeof SOME_ACTION_TYPE>

const actionBuilder2 = action(Symbol('another action type'));
type actionBuilder2Type = typeof actionBuilder2
// expected: () => Action<typeof Symbol('another action type')>
// actual: () => Action<symbol>
```

Here's the string version that works perfectly:

```js
interface Action<T extends string> {
    type: T;
}

function action<T extends string>(type: T): () => Action<T> {
    return () => ({ type });
}

const SOME_ACTION_TYPE = 'some action type';
const actionBuilder = action(SOME_ACTION_TYPE);
type actionBuilderType = typeof actionBuilder;
// expected: () => Action<'some action type'>
// actual: () => Action<'some action type'>

const actionBuilder2 = action('another action type');
type actionBuilder2Type = typeof actionBuilder2
// expected: () => Action<'another action type'>
// actual: () => Action<'another action type'>
```

Comment: Can you explain your "expected"t ype?  `typeof Symbol('another action type')` is not a valid type.   Even if it were it probably wouldn't mean what you want it to mean, since `Symbol('another action type')` produces a unique symbol every time you evaluate it.  You really need some sort of `unique symbol` there, but that's not what you get.  I'm looking in GitHub to see if anyone's run into the lack of anonymous unique symbols for inline `Symbol()` outputs but I haven't found an exact match.

Comment: I think https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37469 is the closest issue; the `Symbol()` constructor is special-cased by the compiler to produce new unique symbols every time it's called, but there's no way to express that in the type system, so it composes poorly.  If there were a `new symbol` type then this would automatically work for you (I think).  Would you like this explanation written up as an answer?  Note that your question is primarily asking what's happening and why, and not for some workaround (so I wouldn't go into that very much).  Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort but I honestly don't get what you mean so the ff is based on what I think you tried to say... I'm not trying to make new symbols every time `action` is called; I just want the objects produced by the `action` function to refer to that same symbol. That `() => Action<typeof Symbol('another action type')>` is just what I think the IDE would show me when I hover the type declaration `actionBuilder2Type`. I think I get what's happening now though because of [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#unique-symbol).

Comment: You want new symbols every time `Symbol()` is called, but when you don't assign it to a variable the type system has no way to express that, so it widens to just `symbol`.  I don't think there's a solution here other than to ask you to give your symbols names.  If that doesn't work for your use case then maybe there's no solution.

Comment: Please let me know if you do or do not want to see an answer here referencing https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37469 and that there's currently no way to have new anonymous unique symbols come out of `Symbol()`.  You can only do that with named symbols.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `'another action type'` in `Symbol('another action type')` is not being infered, because `Symbol` constructor is not parametrized, I mean it does not have generic parameter.

Please see the type signature of `SymbolConstructor`:

```js
interface SymbolConstructor {
    /**
     * A reference to the prototype.
     */
    readonly prototype: Symbol;

    /**
     * Returns a new unique Symbol value.
     * @param  description Description of the new Symbol object.
     */
    (description?: string | number): symbol;

    /**
     * Returns a Symbol object from the global symbol registry matching the given key if found.
     * Otherwise, returns a new symbol with this key.
     * @param key key to search for.
     */
    for(key: string): symbol;

    /**
     * Returns a key from the global symbol registry matching the given Symbol if found.
     * Otherwise, returns a undefined.
     * @param sym Symbol to find the key for.
     */
    keyFor(sym: symbol): string | undefined;
}
```

`description` parameter is always infered as a `string | number`. Further more, `symbol` type is a primitive type and cant be parametrized. However, if you want to parametrize it - you can.

First of all we need to declare own `SymbolConstructor` signature.

```js
interface SymbolConstructor {
    <T extends string>(description: T): symbol & { tag?: T };
}

declare var Symbol: SymbolConstructor;
```

TypeScript will automaticaly merge it with existing one ([see declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)).
You probably have noticed that I have added `{ tag?: T }` to `return type`. It help use to unfer `description` and distinguish `our special` `symbol` from other symbols.

Lets test it:

```js
interface Action<T extends symbol> {
    type: T;
}

interface SymbolConstructor {
    <T extends string>(description: T): symbol & { tag?: T };
}

declare var Symbol: SymbolConstructor;

function action<T extends symbol>(type: T): () => Action<T> {
    return () => ({ type });
}

const actionBuilder2 = action(Symbol('another action type'))

// () => Action<symbol & {
//     tag?: "another action type" | undefined;
// }>
type actionBuilder2Type = typeof actionBuilder2
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WoDYMw)

If you want to infer string part, you should separate it from `Symbol`.

Comment: ehhhh you probably don't want to mess with `Symbol()`'s output.  TypeScript intentionally makes `Symbol()` return unique output types every time it's called, see [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqEYqm).   By doing this, you've destroyed the whole unique symbol aspect, which can have far-reaching consequences in a code base.  If someone does decide to do this they should be warned about it, so you might want to add some big caveats here.

Comment: Thank you for answering but that's not what I was trying to do. I only included the symbol descriptions it to make the sample code readable. Also, adding a tag to a symbol defeats the whole purpose of symbols.I am trying to use symbols instead of strings because I want the symbol description stripped off release builds.